# How to query Postgresql-14 Timestamptz field in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, npgsql, postgresql-14

I use Postgresql-14, I have a timestamptz field named 'start_datetime' like below:

```
select start_datetime from table1

2023-08-01 07:00:00.000 +0700
2023-08-01 07:00:00.000 +0700
2023-08-02 07:00:00.000 +0700
2023-08-03 07:00:00.000 +0700
2023-08-04 07:00:00.000 +0700
2023-08-04 07:00:00.000 +0700
```

How to query date that timestamptz field with C# Code, I expect to query date '2021-08-02' and '2021-08-03'

I use:

- Net Core 6
- Dapper 2.0.143
- Npgsql 7.0.4
- Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 7.0.4

I have tried:

```
select
   t.start_datetime
    from
        table1 t
    where
       to_char(t.start_datetime at time zone 'UTC','YYYY-MM-DD') >=
       '2023-08-02'
        and to_char(c.start_datetime at time zone 'UTC','YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2023-08-03'
```

but it didn't find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `to_char`, consider using [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC):

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', start_datetime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS utc_date
FROM table1
WHERE DATE_TRUNC('day', start_datetime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') BETWEEN '2021-08-02' AND '2021-08-03'
```

You note in your question that you're querying the year 2023 but the table contains only 2021, so that may also be part of the problem you're encountering, or a mistake in framing the question.

Comment: yes, thank you for your info, I have updated the query results.
why I have to move back 1 day to start in my case '2023-08-01' to get the '2023-08-02', is it because the UTC?

Comment: Yes, I believe so :)